# In Excel, Move the end of a URL to another cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a column of a few thousand URLs. I would like to copy the end of the URL and move it into an empty column. For example:

I have this:

```
/downloads/employeeresources/ucm649871.pdf
```

but I want this:

```
/downloads/employeeresources/ucm649871.pdf      ucm649871.pdf
```

Is there a function that I can run to achieve this?

Even better if I can strip the suffix:

```
/downloads/employeeresources/ucm649871.pdf      ucm649871
```

Thanks!

Comment: is the string you want always followed by `employeeresources/`? Or would it be better to assume you want all of the text after the last instance of `/`?

Comment: No. the URLs are different.  All of the text after the last "/" is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your data is as static as your sample then this is pretty straight forward then we can assumes the file name is always in the folder `employeeresources/` and that your file extension is always `.pdf`

```
=SUBSTITUTE(MID(D156,SEARCH("employeeresources/",D156)+18,LEN(D156)),".pdf","")
```

---

If not, you can use something like below to extract **all** text after the **last** `/` which includes your extension

```
=MID(SUBSTITUTE(D148,"/","@@@",LEN(D148)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(D148,"/",""))),SEARCH("@@@",SUBSTITUTE(D148,"/","@@@",LEN(D148)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(D148,"/",""))))+3,LEN(D148))
```

---

### VBA Solution

If you are open to using VBA, you can use the below UDF to extract your file name by simply calling the formula `GET_FILENAME(range)`. Note that this solution is the most dynamic of the 3. It will extract all text after the last `/` while excluding the last 4 characters (file extension)

```
Public Function GET_FILENAME(Target As Range) As String

Dim Temp, i As Long

Temp = Split(Target, "/")
i = UBound(Temp)

GET_FILENAME = Left(Temp(i), Len(Temp(i)) - 4)

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Another VBA solution is:

```
Function ExtractResource(strUrl As String)
Dim strResult As String

'extract the resource file:  ucm649871.pdf
strResult = Right(strUrl, Len(strUrl) - InStrRev(strUrl, "/"))

'remove the file extension:   ucm649871
strResult = Left(strResult, InStrRev(strResult, ".") - 1)

ExtractResource = strResult
End Function
```

You may just type =ExtractResource("Cell that contains the URL") to your destination cell.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could use (including suffix):

```
=FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[last()]")
```

Excluding suffix:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[last()]"),".pdf","")
```

Or with a little bit more flexibility on the extension:

```
=FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,".","/"),"/","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[last()-1]")
```